# How to deploy the jar files into liferay running on docker from local machine?

Tags: docker, liferay

I have a Liferay instance running on docker. I need to deploy some jar files, I created shared folders from the virtual box but none of them are shown in docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling shared folders via virtual box won't work in the docker container.

Open kitematic, there you can see the container in which your Liferay is running. Now open the container and look for "volumes" menu. Under "Volumes" menu you can see "/workspace", select that folder.This will create a shared folder b/w local and Docker container. Select 'auto-mount' option. This folder will be usually under "Documents/kitematic/{name-of-container}/workspace". Copy all jars inside here. Now go inside the docker container via bash. Now you can copy all jars from "/workspace" to "/opt/liferay-*/deploy".